# sdo_relate giving a wrong query result

Tags: oracle, geospatial, intersect, spatial-query, oracle-spatial

I have two geometry in two feature class ,one named "HY90299 " and the other named "hyboxsdo " ,the two geometry do not intersect .

but when i run a spatial query in oralce  ,

"select  sdo_relate(t.shape,g.shape ,'mask=ANYINTERACT')  from HY90299 t,hyboxsdo g "  ,

it return "true", the result is not correct .am I doing something wrong?

my oracle version is 11g

```
you can get the two geometry by 

1.i put the  two geometry into two shape file . you can get them from here
https://pan.baidu.com/s/1YQnwe8nstzgHOAwHgx9JGQ

2.or create the two geometry  by wkt
①MULTIPOLYGON (((-16.657423019000021 82.843477248999989, 16.710901260000014 66.242341995000004, 74.611375808999981 57.038061142000004, 111.18630027799998 67.126588820999984, -16.657423019000021 82.843477248999989)))
②MULTIPOLYGON (((60.839999999999975 26.569999999999993, 143.45000000000005 26.569999999999993, 143.45000000000005 55.75, 60.839999999999975 55.75, 60.839999999999975 26.569999999999993)))
```

Append

```
1.select * from user_sdo_geom_metadata where table_name='HY90299'

=============================

return "HY90299    SHAPE     {{null,-180,180,0.001},{null,-90,90,0.001}}    4326"



2.select sdo_geom.validate_geometry_with_context(c.shape,0.000000005) from  hy90299 c
   select sdo_geom.validate_geometry_with_context(c.shape,0.001) from hy90299 c

=============================

all return  "true"



3.select shape from hy90299

=============================

return "{2003,4326,null,{1,1003,1},{111.186300278,67.126588821,-16.657423019,82.843477249,16.71090126,66.242341995,74.611375809,57.038061142,111.186300278,67.126588821}}"



4.select sdo_geom.relate(t.shape,'determine',sdo_geometry(2003,4326,null, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,3),SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(60.840,26.570,143.450,55.750)),0.000000005) as spat_rel from HY90299 t

=============================

return "DISJOINT"



5.select sdo_geom.relate(t.shape,'determine',sdo_geometry(2003,4326,null, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1),SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(60.840,26.570, 143.450,26.570, 143.450,55.750,60.840,55.750,60.840, 26.570)),0.000000005) as spat_rel from HY90299 t

=============================

return "OVERLAPBDYINTERSECT"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_operat.htm#SPATL1039), spatial **operators** "must always be used in a WHERE clause", not in the SELECT part of the query.

To use them (in the WHERE clause, as mentioned), they must be spatially indexed.

If you want to see the spatial relation, you can use one of the spatial **functions** - e.g:

```
select t.*,g.*, sdo_geom.relate(t.shape,'determine',g.shape,0.000000005) as spat_rel
from HY90299 t, hyboxsdo g
```

If you want you can add the function to the WHERE caluse as well, to filter the results - e.g. add in the above snippet:

```
where sdo_geom.relate(t.shape,'determine',g.shape,0.000000005) not in ('TOUCH','DISJOINT')
```

For a handful of geometries, you'll be fine. As the number of geometries grows, you must either use spatial indexes and add operator(s) in the WHERE clause, or device another way to filter the rows (e.g. by an attribute, id, etc) - spatial functions do not scale well.

You also have the responsibility to choose the TOLERANCE value that is appropriate for your data and query (I chose 0.000000005 as your shapes seem to have 8 significant decimals).

Last, BUT NOT LEAST, you'd want to make certain that your geometries are valid (again, at the appropriate tolerance).

HTH

APPEND:
1)

```
with HY90299 as (
  select sdo_util.from_wktgeometry( 
  'MULTIPOLYGON (((-16.657423019000021 82.843477248999989, 16.710901260000014 66.242341995000004, 74.611375808999981 57.038061142000004, 111.18630027799998 67.126588820999984, -16.657423019000021 82.843477248999989)))'
  ) shape from dual ), 
HYBOXSDO as (
  select sdo_util.from_wktgeometry( 
  'MULTIPOLYGON (((60.839999999999975 26.569999999999993, 143.45000000000005 26.569999999999993, 143.45000000000005 55.75, 60.839999999999975 55.75, 60.839999999999975 26.569999999999993)))'
  ) shape  from dual )
select sdo_geom.relate(t.shape,'determine',g.shape,0.000000005)
from HY90299 t,hyboxsdo g ;
```

The result is DISJOINT - also:

```
with HY90299 as (
select sdo_geometry(2003,4326,null, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1),SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(-16.657423019000021, 82.843477248999989, 16.710901260000014, 66.242341995000004, 74.611375808999981, 57.038061142000004, 111.18630027799998, 67.126588820999984, -16.657423019000021, 82.843477248999989))
 shape from dual )
select sdo_geom.relate(t.shape,'determine',
sdo_geometry(2003,4326,null, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,3),SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(60.840,26.570,143.450,55.750))
,0.000000005) as spat_rel from HY90299 t
```

The result is, again, DISJOINT.
Your 'overlapbdyintersect' shouldn't be there - check the contents of your tables (since the difference in your two queries is the 'window' geometry, double check the hyboxsdo table).
2) You are wrong. Tolerance **is** essential. If you use `sdo_geom.relate(t.shape,'determine',g.shape,2)` -that is a tolerance of 2 meters- in the above queries, you will get TOUCH instead of DISJOINT (and by this, you can also tell that your geometries are roughly 2m apart). However, with these two geometries, you would never get OVERLAP.
3) A geometry's validity is directly related to the tolerance you use. Your geometries **are** valid (in 8 decimals) - I'm just saying that it will save you LOTS of headaches if you don't take it for granted. Never assume - check!
4) It doesn't matter *how* you put the geometries in the table. The only think you *might* want to consider (especially in production environments) is the number of decimals stored in the database - if your data make good sense at a precision of, say, 3 decimals, you'd be better off rounding or truncating your coordinates to that. Simpler coordinates lead to smaller footprint (database storage) and faster performance.

Comment: thanks for your answer!
1. I tried that query   "select t.*,g.*, sdo_geom.relate(t.shape,'determine',g.shape,0.000000005) as spat_rel
from HY90299 t, hyboxsdo g" ,  it still return overlapbyintersect  

2.one geometry has minY of 57.038  the other has maxY of 55.750  i don't think the TOLERANCE is the reason which casue that result

3.the two geometry are very simple geometry ,which only have four point .they should be valid

Comment: 4.I create the feature class and import the features by arcgis.Does it has effection on the spatial query ?

5.I run the query in other way " select t.*, sdo_geom.relate(t.shape,'determine',sdo_geometry(2003,4326,null, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,3),SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(60.840,26.570,143.450,55.750)),0.000000005) as spat_rel
from HY90299 t" ,it return the correct result -disjoint.
the geometry in hyboxsdo has lower left of (60.840,26.570) and the upper right(143.450,55.750)
the query is same in some way ,by giving diffent result.i don't understand why

Comment: hope for your reply and sorry for my poor english

Comment: See APEND in my answer.

Comment: see my append also. <pre> </pre>

Comment: The two geometry 'unit is decimal  degree. one minY is 57.038,the other maxY is 55.750 how can it be possble that ther are   2m apart.I try to  projected the two geometry with mecator,they are at least  1000 meter apart

Comment: About the distance, my bad - I ran it without reprojecting. My point, however, was that the geometries were indeed disjoint.   I do not understand the last part of your Append: You are querying for the relation of the HY90299 geometry, but the 'window' geometries (the ones after 'determine') are different in your (4) and (5). Am I missing something here?